# Can anyone confirm this issue (limited number of file descriptors on some Android devices)?

Tags: android, galaxy

I'm currently working on a cool Android game which was about to be released real soon. Some of our beta testers started complaining that the game crashes with the “too many open files” error message. I've tried simulating this problem on the AVD emulator but couldn't reproduce the error.

Afterwards, I realized that only our Galaxy S3 and Asus Nexus 7 testers were complaining.
I found [this bug issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39002) on Android's bug tracker and it sounds quite similar to what is happening to me.

This sounds like a serious architecture problem which effects all internal SD card devices. 
These devices are limited to only 1024 file descriptors!
Can anybody confirm this problem?

Comment: How many open files does your program have?

Comment: How many files did your application opens and how much memory did they take.! The size of the files might be increasing as of the device's internal memory.!

Answer (score 5):

Actually it is not relevant whether this app is opening a lot of files or not.
What's troubling is that the **entire device** is limited to 1024 open files.
Take for instance a Galaxy S3 device running 100 apps each opening 10 files concurrently(properties, databases and the like). This is extremely close to the limit.

If you check the max open files limit (/proc/sys/fs/file-max) on most devices it is well over 50K.

Comment: I doubt that 100 apps could be running at any one time, 10 even. It's not a huge issue if you consider that memory is limited, apps quickly get killed or suspended where they should take care to tidy up.

Comment: That's true but still it could happen. The new devices like the nexus4 come with 2GB RAM. That's a computer. It can easily run 100 apps.

Comment: @alechko: 100 processes is probably still a bit high, given the heap size per process. However, your point is still valid: a bunch of apps with a bunch of open files could consume all file descriptors.

Comment: note, it's not just files - sockets too. Plus, if the app has a bug (not an excuse, but it happens, you know :) and leaks FDs, limit can be reached pretty fast. Result: one buggy app f**ks up whole device.