# Apparently creating File fails on Android on native side if already lots of AssetFileDescriptors exist

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, superpowered

For benchmarking purposes I repeat loading data from an asset and processing it with the Superpowered SDK. For opening the asset with the Superpowered SDK I create an `AssetFileDescripter afd` on java side and make a JNI call with the path to the apk, `afd.getStartOffset()` and `afd.getLength()` as parameters. In this JNI function I load the asset with a SuperpoweredDecoder and create a new file (`/storage/emulated/0/result.wav`) for saving the result.

The Problem is that when I create a new `AssetFileDescripter` in each benchmark iteration on java side creating the file `/storage/emulated/0/result.wav` with the Superpowered SDK fails after 971 iterations, or most of the time 995 iterations.

If I use only one and the same `AssetFileDescripter` for all iterations, all works fine and I can make 1000 or more benchmark iterations. 
Does anybody have ideas? (The android version of my testing device is 4.4.2)

I would be thankful for all hints.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262339/can-anyone-confirm-this-issue-limited-number-of-file-descriptors-on-some-androi seems relevant.

Comment: Thanks, you inspired me to close the AssetFileDescriptor in each iteration. I have somehow forgot to do this.

Comment: Can We convert our internal storage file to AssetFileDescripter ? Please tell me how your code is worked for playing storage music @Sebastian

Comment: no, becasue the AssetFileDescriptor is used for assets (= raw files bundled with the application) and not for other storage like the internal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing the asset file descriptor after each iteration solved my problem. There really seems to be a device-dependent limit concerning open file descriptors. (Follow link to question in comments)